# Occurance of selected words in a text c++

Tags: c++

I'm doing a research in linguistics and I need some help.

I have a list of names in a text file (names.txt) 
and I need to find out how many times all the words that are in this file occur in another text file (data.txt).

So far I found a manual way by writing each word from the names.txt file in a string by hand. Is there a shorter way to solve this?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   ifstream file("names.txt");
   ifstream file("data.txt")

int wcount = 0;

string token;

string word("Jhon");   //here I write names which are supposed to be taken
string word1("James"); //from names.txt automatically
string word2("Rick");
string word3("Morty");
string word4("Alice");
string word5("Tina");
string word6("Timmy");
// ...         

while (file>>token) //here I check if those words exist in data.txt
    if ((word == token) || (word1== token)|| (word2 == token) || (word3== token)|| (word4 == token) || (word5== token) || (word6==token))

    wcount++;

cout << wcount << endl;



    return 0;
```

Comment: What's your question ? you need us to write code for you ?

Comment: Replace word1...n  with a std::vector

Comment: Store all words from "names.txt" in a `std::set<std::string>`. In the loop that parses words from "data.txt", call `std::set::find(token)` to check if the word exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `std::vector<std::string>` to hold the dictionary and `std::find` to look up words.  Some people might argue that the find algorithm of `std::set` is faster than that of `std::vector` but you need a really huge number of elements before this algorithm outperforms the gain you get from `std::vector` being in consecutive memory.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream names("names.txt");
  std::ifstream data("data.txt");

  std::vector<std::string> words = { "Jhon", "James", "Rick", "Morty", "Alice", "Tina", "Timmy" };

  int wcount = 0;
  std::string token;
  while (data >> token) //here I check if those words exist in data.txt
    if (std::find(std::begin(words), std::end(words), token) != std::end(words))
      ++wcount;

  std::cout << wcount << '\n';
}
```